# Return timeslot array based on begin and end time in PHP

Tags: php

I need your help with the following issue. I'm building a website, using PHP, on which I'd like to display a calendar showing the days of the week, with each day subdivided into 3 timeslots. These timeslots are either free, or booked, in which case that timeslot is not selectable.

So far so good, but the problem lies in displaying the timeslots as booked. I'm getting the booking data from a script which gives me an start date and time, and an end date and time. These date/time stamps can be anything and aren't bound to timeslot times. They can be on the same day, or span multiple days. The timeslots are the same for each day: from 9 to 13, 13 to 17, and 19 to 23 hrs.

For example, say I have a start time of 17-12-2012 13:00, and an end time of 18-12-2012 11:00, I want my function to give me an array like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["meetingroom1_booked"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-17"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-17"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-18"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I've been racking my brain over this, but can't come up with a good solution that deals with start-end times span multiple days. With begin and end time on a single day, it's no problem: I can compare the start-end hours to the timeslot hours. This doesn't work for multiple days though of course. Any pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this article while I look at your data here. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_201-Handling-date-and-time-in-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method with simple algorithm:

```
<?php
$start_date = '2012-12-17';
$start_time = '13:00';
$end_date = '2012-12-18';
$end_time = '11:00';
$slots = array(1=>'09:00', 2=>'13:00', 3=>'19:00');

// [helper]
$start_date_stamp = strtotime($start_date);
$end_date_stamp = strtotime($end_date);
$startdate_timestamp = strtotime($start_date . ' ' . $start_time);
$enddate_timestamp = strtotime($end_date . ' ' . $end_time);
// [/helper]

$cur_date_stamp = $start_date_stamp;
$result = array();
if ($enddate_timestamp >= $startdate_timestamp) {
    // [loop for each date]
    while($cur_date_stamp <= $end_date_stamp) {
        foreach($slots as $slkey=>$slval) {
            if ($cur_date_stamp == $start_date_stamp) { // compare for current date = start date
                $check_slot_stamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $cur_date_stamp) . ' ' . $slval);
                if ($startdate_timestamp <= $check_slot_stamp) {
                    $result[] = array(
                        'day' => date('Y-m-d', $cur_date_stamp),
                        'timeslot' => $slkey
                    );
                }
            }
            elseif ($cur_date_stamp == $end_date_stamp) { // compare for current date = end date
                $check_slot_stamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $cur_date_stamp) . ' ' . $slval);
                if ($check_slot_stamp <= $enddate_timestamp) {
                    $result[] = array(
                        'day' => date('Y-m-d', $cur_date_stamp),
                        'timeslot' => $slkey
                    );
                }
            }
            else { // 3 slots will be added for any date other than start_date and end_date
                $result[] = array(
                    'day' => date('Y-m-d', $cur_date_stamp),
                    'timeslot' => $slkey
                );
            }
        }
        $cur_date_stamp = strtotime('+1 day', $cur_date_stamp); // next day
    }
    // [/loop for each date]
}
$result = array('meetingroom1_booked'=>$result);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic function I came up with that might help. My calculation of the 'time slot' may not match up exactly to what you desire but you can probably update this to suit your needs.

```php
$res = calc('01-12-2012 09:00', '01-12-2012 13:00');
print_r($res);
$res = calc('17-12-2012 13:00', '18-12-2012 11:00');
print_r($res);

function calc($start, $end) {
    // generic way to determine time slot; value is the high hour.
    static $slots = array(1 => 13, 2 => 17, 3 => 23);

    $oneDay = new \DateInterval("P1D");

    if (!($start instanceof \DateTime)) {
        $start = date_create($start);
    }
    if (!($end instanceof \Datetime)) {
        $end = date_create($end);
    }

    $ary = array();
    $now = clone $start;
    do {
        $res = array('day' => $now->format('Y-m-d'));
        foreach ($slots as $idx => $hour) {
            if ($now->format('H') <= $hour) {
                $res['slot'] = $idx;
                break;
            }
        }
        $ary[] = $res;

        $now->add($oneDay);
    } while ($now->format('Y-m-d') <= $end->format('Y-m-d'));

    return $ary;
}
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2012-12-01
            [slot] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2012-12-17
            [slot] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2012-12-18
            [slot] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to test out OK. http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_daan.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_daan.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* PROBLEM DEFINITION
The timeslots are the same for each day: from 9 to 13, 13 to 17, and 19 to 23 hrs.

For example, say I have a start time of 17-12-2012 13:00, and an end time of 18-12-2012 11:00, I want my function to give me an array like this:

array(1) {
  ["meetingroom1_booked"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-17"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-17"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(10) "2012-12-18"
      ["timeslot"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
*/

// THE TIMEZONE
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

// THE START AND END TIMES
$alpha = '2012-12-17 13:00';
$omega = '2012-12-18 11:00';

// THE DEFINITION OF THE TIMESLOTS
$slots = array
( 1 => array
       ( 'lo' => '0900'
       , 'hi' => '1259'
       )
, 2 => array
       ( 'lo' => '1300'
       , 'hi' => '1659'
       )
, 3 => array
       ( 'lo' => '1900'
       , 'hi' => '2259'
       )
)
;

// MAKE AN ARRAY OF TIMESTAMPS OF THE HOURS
$tsa = strtotime($alpha);
$tsz = strtotime($omega);
$hours = range($tsa, $tsz, 3600);

// ASSIGN EACH HOUR TO A SLOT
foreach ($hours as $hour)
{
    $hhmm = date('Hi', $hour);
    foreach ($slots as $slot => $times)
    {
        if ($hhmm >= $times['lo'])
        {
            if ($hhmm <= $times['hi'])
            {
                // USE STRING NOTATION HERE SO WE CAN USE ARRAY_UNIQUE()
                $taken[$hour] = date('Y-m-d', $hour) . '|' . $slot;
            }
        }
    }
}
// REMOVE THE REDUNDANCIES
$taken = array_unique($taken);

// CONSTRUCT THE ASSOCIATIVE ARRAYS
foreach($taken as $thing)
{
    $arr = explode('|', $thing);
    $out[] = array('day' => $arr[0], 'timeslot' => $arr[1]);
}
// CONSTRUCT THE FINAL ARRAY
$out = array("meetingroom1_booked" => $out);

// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your time to UNIX TIMESTAMP you can simply do this check.

The current timestamp is: 1355757162
Timestamp tommorow 5 o'clock: 1355846439

Every timestamp greater then 1355757162 and smaller then 1355846439 should be booked.